# AKS: CI/CD pipeline using AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-container-service

I'm trying to figure out the steps to setup CI/CD for an Asp.Net Core web application using AKS with VSTS. Are the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/azure/deploy-container-kubernetes  valid for what I'm trying to do? Are windows container supported in AKS?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in ASP.Net Core, then you can host it in Linux as your code is platform independent. I have done this using Docker-file where your container is a self hosted app running on AKS.

VSTS provides a Inbuilt task to deploy to your AKS cluster in your build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Windows support on k8s is better with Windows Server version 1709 which needs Kubernetes v1.9 (bleeding edge stable).  See https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/

Unfortunately, at this time, AKS preview only supports up to 1.8.2.

Comment: Thanks. If I decide to use linux cluster for now, are CI/CD steps in the link in my question applicable to AKS?

Comment: The instructions are for ACI but will work with AKS (the registry they use is Azure Container Registry - usable from anywhere).

They don't actually tell you how to deploy vsts, seem to presume you already have a working vsts so it may not be what you want if starting from scratch.

Comment: The highest supported version in the preview is now 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Frosty, if you can create a docker image out of your Windows machine, it can be pushed to the container registry and then deployed to Kubernetes cluster. Here are some links for reference:

Building and Pushing Windows container images: https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/

Install Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Create Kubernetes cluster in AKS: https://coderise.io/kubernetes-cluster-on-azure-container-service/

Answer (score 0):

Windows containers are in private preview in AKS ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-run-windows-server-containers-on-aks)); you can sign up using [this form.](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1zIfQJ4OeJCrEAguCCqD5dUOUJCUU1CMkFMV0I4UUtDUENCOTUxWEg1SC4u). You can run hybrid clusters (Linux+Windows, up to 1803) using [acs-engine today](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/windows.md).

The VSTS walkthrough you linked is valid; check also [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/03/27/building-microservices-with-aks-and-vsts-part-1/) and [this one.](https://dgkanatsios.com/2017/05/29/creating-a-cicd-pipeline-on-azure-container-services-with-kubernetes-and-visual-studio-team-services/)

Update: Windows support for AKS is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Windows container are only in private preview, and you need to enable it using Azure CLI do some steps, please refer this official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli. After you enable it, then you can check the 'Windows Container' option when you create node pool in your azure kubernete service account.